# ntohl() returning 0 when reading from mmap()

Tags: c++, memory, mmap

Good evening, I am attempting to read some binary information from a .img file. I can retrieve 16-bit numbers (uint16_t) from ntohs(), but when I try to retrieve from the same position using ntohl(), it gives me 0 instead.

Here are the critical pieces of my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cmath>

int fd;
struct blockInfo {
    long blockSize = 0;
    long blockCount = 0;
    long fatStart = 0;
    long fatBlocks = 0;
    long rootStart = 0;
    long rootBlocks = 0;
    long freeBlocks = 0;
    long resBlocks = 0;
    long alloBlocks = 0;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);

   // Get file size
   struct stat buf{};
   stat(path, &buf);
   size_t size = buf.st_size;

   // A struct to hold data retrieved from a big endian image.
   blockInfo info;

   auto mapPointer = (char*) mmap(nullptr, size,
                     (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE), MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

   info.blockSize = ntohs((uint16_t) mapPointer[12]);
   long anotherBlockSize = ntohl((uint32_t) mapPointer[11]);

   printf("%ld", info.blockSize); // == 512, correct
   printf("%ld", anotherBlockSize); // == 0, what?
}
```

I understand that `blockSize` and `anotherBlockSize` are not supposed to be equal, but `anotherBlockSize` should be non-zero at the least, right?

Something else, I go to access data at `ntohs(pointer[16])`, which should return 2, but also returns 0. What is going on here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that value of `mapPointer[11]` is not zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `anotherBlockSize` will not necessarily be non-zero

```
info.blockSize = ntohs((uint16_t) mapPointer[12]);
```

This code **reads a char from offset 12** relatively to mapPointer, casts it to uint16_t and applies ntohs() to it.

```
long anotherBlockSize = ntohl((uint32_t) mapPointer[11]);
```

This code **reads a char from offset 11** relatively to mapPointer, casts it to uint32_t and applies ntohl() to it.

Obviously, you are reading non-overlapped data (different chars) from the mapped memory, so you should not expect `blockSize` and `anotherBlockSize` to be connected.

If you are trying to read the same memory in different ways (as uint32_t and uint16_t), you must do some pointer casting:

```
info.blockSize = ntohs( *((uint16_t*)&mapPointer[12]));
```

Note that such code will generally be platform dependent. Such cast working perfectly on x86 may fail on ARM.

Comment: Apparently, I need to brush up on pointers and references. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
auto mapPointer = (char*)  ...
```

This declares `mapPointer` to be a `char *`.

```
... ntohl((uint32_t) mapPointer[11]);
```

Your obvious intent here is to use `mapPointer` to retrieve a 32 bit value, a four-byte value, from this location.

Unfortunately, because `mapPointer` is a plain, garden-variety `char *`, the expression `mapPointer[11]` evaluates to a single, lonely `char` value. One byte. That's what the code reads from the `mmap`ed memory block, at the 11th offset from the start of the block. The `(uint32_t)` does not read an `uint32_t` from the address referenced `mapPointer+11`.  `mapPointer[11]` reads a single `char` value from `mapPointer+11`, because `mapPointer` is a pointer to a `char`, converts it to a `uint32_t`, and feeds to to `ntohl()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! You did a great job at helping me understand how I was incorrectly reading from memory.

Only one byte exists at each index, so doing something like `ntohs((uint16_t) mapPointer[11])` won't be able to access sequential memory. It was just taking that byte as the most significant half and appending an empty byte because it couldn't find anything else.